# Writing and importing custom modules/classes

Tags: python, python-2.6

I've got a class that I'm trying to write called dbObject and I'm trying to import it from a script in a different folder. My structure is as follows:

```
/var/www/html/py/testobj.py

/var/www/html/py/obj/dbObject.py

/var/www/html/py/obj/__init__.py
```

Now, `__init__.py` is an empty file. Here are the contents of dbObject.py:

```
class dbObject:
        def __init__():
                print "Constructor?"

        def test():
                print "Testing"
```

And here's the contents of testobj.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
sys.path.append("/var/www/html/py")
import obj.dbObject

db = dbObject()
```

When I run this, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testobj.py", line 7, in <module>
    db = dbObject()
NameError: name 'dbObject' is not defined
```

I'm new to Python, so I'm very confused as to what I'm doing wrong. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Thanks to Martijn Pieters' answer I modified my testobj.py as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
sys.path.append("/var/www/html/py")
sys.path.append("/var/www/html/py/dev")
from  obj.dbObject import dbObject

db = dbObject()
```

However, now when I run it I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testobj.py", line 7, in <module>
    db = dbObject()
TypeError: __init__() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Is this referring to my **init**.py or the constructor within dbObject?

EDIT(2): Solved that one myself, the constructor must be able to take at least one parameter - a reference to itself. Simple fix. Looks like this problem is solved!

EDIT (Final): This is nice - I can cut out the import sys and sys.path.append lines and it still works in this instance. Lovely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the class from the module:

```
from obj.dbObject import dbObject
```

This adds the class `dbObject` directly to your local namespace.

Your statement `import obj.dbObject` adds the name `obj` to the local namespace, so you could also do this instead:

```
db = obj.dbObject.dbObject()
```

because `obj.dbObject` is the `dbObject.py` module in your `obj` package directory.

Comment: if you use a `from X import Y` statement, then your code should be using `Y` to refer to the imported object. `obj.dbObject.dbObject()` would fail with the error message `NameError: name 'obj' is not defined`